# HTML request for XSLT 2.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt-2.0, mixitup

I have previously worked with xml and xslt 1.0 displayed as html pages. I used the html request suggested by W3Schools (function loadXMLDoc).

Now I would like to start a new project where I use xml and xslt 2.0 and I guess still display the result as html pages. What would be the best way (and as simple as possible) to display xslt 2.0 in html?

A few notes to my question:

1) I have experienced some issues when updating xml files. The html page isn't updated right away with the new data from the xml files - not even after I refreshed the page.

2) I will sometimes be needing to use data from more than one xml file in the same xslt 2.0 sheet.

3) I would like to combine my xslt 2.0 sheet with the MixItUp js-script (https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/). This last note is the least important.

My previous project with xml and xslt 1.0 displayed as html can be seen here (http://www.halfmen.dk/). I am not an expert in any way - as you for sure have noticed in my way of describing my question. I think that the best way for me to understand this complicated information would be in the use of examples.

Thank you in advance. McClaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the browsers support XSLT 2.0 natively. However, you can use XSLT 2.0 in the browser via the Saxon-CE library. See the documentation at http://www.saxonica.com/ce/user-doc/1.1/index.html (which is itself rendered using Saxon-CE).

Comment: I have chosen to try another solution - namely php. Thank you for your answer. :o)